# Crystal Report export to excel using PHP without Excel Format Options

Tags: php, crystal-reports

I'm using following code for export crystal report to excel using PHP.

```
$file_name="fileanme";

$my_report = getcwd()."\\crystal\\".$file_name.".rpt"; //rpt source file
$my_excel = getcwd()."\\temp\\".$file_name.".xls"; // RPT export to pdf file
$OBJ="CrystalReports115.ObjectFactory.1";
$ObjectFactory= new COM($OBJ) or die ("Error on load"); // call COM port
$crapp = $ObjectFactory-> CreateObject("CrystalDesignRunTime.Application"); // create an instance for Crystal

$creport = $crapp->OpenReport($my_report, 1); // call rpt report

$DSNName = "APLERP_ODBC";
$creport->DiscardSavedData;
$creport->Database->Tables(1)->SetLogOnInfo ($DSNName, "apex_pharma", "abid", "12345");

$creport->EnableParameterPrompting = 0;

$creport->ReadRecords();
$creport->ExportOptions->DiskFileName=$my_excel; //export to excel
$creport->ExportOptions->PDFExportAllPages=true;
$creport->ExportOptions->DestinationType=1; // export to file

$creport->ExportOptions->FormatType=29; // Excel type

$creport->Export(false);
$creport = null;
$crapp = null;
$ObjectFactory = null;
```

When I browse the page, the following dialog box show in my server. Before click on button, server become busy.

How can I avoid it?

[image: Excel Format Options]

Comment: what is following message...? did u forget to post...?

Comment: Sorry,
Actually I want to avoid this dialog box.